# Сравнение двух таблиц с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

```css
  tr {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<table id="tab1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tab2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>0</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Как сравнить содержимое двух таблиц с помощью jquery.Если они не одинаковые, то вывести сообщение

Comment: Это учебное задание? Число строк/столбцов точно совпадает, и нужно сравнить только значения в ячейках?

Answer (score 1):

Если точно известно, что число строк и столбцов совпадает, можно просто через jQuery выбрать все ячейки (элементы `<td>` и `<th>`) в каждой из таблиц, и пробежаться, сравнивая значения до первого несовпадения:

```js
var t1 = $('#tab1')
    ,cells1 = $('td,th', t1)
    ,t2 = $('#tab2')
    ,cells2 = $('td,th', t2)
    ,i
;

for( i=0; i<cells1.length; i++) {
  var v1 = cells1[i].innerHTML
      ,v2 = cells2[i].innerHTML
  ;
  if( v1 == v2) continue;
  
  // сюда попадаем только когда не равны значения
  alert("о, ужас! "+v1+" не равно "+v2);
  break;
}
```

```css
table, td, th { border-collapse: collapse;border:1px solid #CCC; margin-bottom:10px} td {text-align: center;width: 45px;height: 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tab2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>0</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```